# Can't ever get the new method of aligning to center to work

Tags: html, css

I'm used to using `<center>` but now that it is depricated I've been having a rough time using the recommended `margin` property. Can anyone give me some information on how I can use the "better" way to align to center?

HTML

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="content_container">
        <div id="form_contact">
                <form method="post" action="index.php" style="display:inline">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" style="display:inline">
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" style="display:inline"><br>
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="30" style="display:inline"></textarea><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" class="submit" style="display:inline">
                </form
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header_container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    bottom:95px;
}

#main_container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#content_container {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: depending on what you use it for, you can also use `text-align:center` on the parent element

Comment: The issue is that `margin` does not work most of the time for me.

Comment: text-align: center for centering text. margin: 0 auto for aligning divs on a page

Comment: @VikingBlooded how would I center a `form` in the center of the page?

Comment: Google this issue first.

Comment: @user3735481 make sure the margin: 0 auto is on your wrapper div, not it's contained elements.

Comment: @AliImran I've been searching for help for over 2 days.

Comment: @VikingBlooded I just tested it and it did not work. I will post the code that i'm working on.

Comment: your width is 100%....

Comment: The issue is the item to be centered has to have a width that can be centered. You have 100% width of 100% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.wrapper {
                width: 1000px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form>
            some inputs
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK here is a quick fix to your problem(I think). All you need to do is a add a couple lines of code to your css.

```
html, body { margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
}

body { 
text-align: center; 
}



#header_container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
bottom:95px;
}

#main_container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#content_container {
width:100%;
margin:0;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/gmZ6v/

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the below CSS.

```
 #form_contact {
            display: block;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            text-align:center;
        }
```